# changing ui for and android app

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I am making a video app and on the screen I want to have an image review and play button and some description text. I want to make the image full width of the screen and the play button in the middle of the image. Then the text should be under the button and image.

Below is what I currently am getting with the below layout

[image]

**my layout**

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">


<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:background="@color/list_second_white"
        android:id="@+id/relative_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative_header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/video_thumb_small"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/list_second_white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

On the first image, the button isn't overlapping the Image preview completely.

Comment: Is that image what you want or what you are getting with the current layout?

Comment: this the images is what i have at the moment [img link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uEpQu.png)
i wanna make it like this [img link](http://s10.postimg.org/x834mjw2h/image.jpg) (just i maked quick wireframe for example )

Comment: My antivirus doesn't want me to visit the second link. Can you post it on imgur.com and I will add the image to your post?

Comment: yeah here is http://imgur.com/U8ryUQp
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i would solve the problem will be ..

```
--ScrollView
  --LinearLayout 
    --RelativeLayout
      --TextView
      --TextView
    --FrameLayout
      --ImageView
      --ImageView
    --TextView
    --TextView
```

LinearLayout with orientation vertical will place views inside it one after another. Note : Each layout is occupying whole width of parent layout.

RelativeLayout as you know to place child views relative to each other or parent.

FrameLayout to put one view on top of another

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">


<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/list_second_white"
    android:id="@+id/relative_header">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:src="@drawable/video_thumb_small" />

</FrameLayout>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/list_second_white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

> Update :

try adding

```
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    //will put text in center
```

to `@+id/text`

also add

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    // will scale preview image
```

to `@+id/picture`

also in `ImageView` with `android:src="@drawable/video_thumb_small"`

change

```
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    // will center the play button
```

Comment: am really thank full for your help
this the result [img  link](http://s9.postimg.org/90xm4djbj/Untitled_2.jpg)
am trying to make it like this [img link](http://s10.postimg.org/x834mjw2h/image.jpg)

Comment: You should explain what you changed and ***why*** it should work for the OP instead of just posting code

Comment: @codeMagic okay, i will update my ans, gimme few mins

Comment: @codeMagic i have updated my ans. I hope it helps the OP understand more how it is working